# Is the subset $w = \{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})/ x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2} ≤ 1\}$ of the vector space $V_{3}(R)$ is a subspace of $V_{3}(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\alpha = (a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}), \beta = (b_{1},b_{2},b_{3}) \in V_{3} \subset w(F=R)$

I need to show $\alpha+\beta \leq1$. How do I do that in a generalized way, without using some random vectors and substituting them to check if it's greater than $1$.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The way you defined the set $w$ is confusing me. Did you mean $$w:=\{ (x_1,x_2,x_3)| x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}\leq1\} ?$$ Moreover, I do not see why you need to show $\alpha+\beta\leq1$. Also, you should provide relevant context and show your attempts for the MSE community to not flag this down.

Comment: I believe along with the correct definition of $w$, you would want to show that $$|\alpha|^{2}+|\beta|^{2} \leq1 ?$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not a subspace because it is not closed under addition. Take $u = (1,0,0), v = (0,1,0) \implies u+v = (1,1,0) \notin w$.